# Converting and working with char** and char*

Tags: c, pointers

I have a function call that passes a command line as a parameter and is defined as follows:

```
process_raw_cmdline(char** line)
{
      //
}
```

I would like to eventually read through this line and break it down to use parts of the line as parameters for other things.  What would be a good way to take this line and save different "words" broken up by spaces.  I'll also eventually have to convert parts of this line into integers.

Comment: Is this the same as the second parameter to the `main` function (commonly called `argv`)? Then this is not a line but an array of strings.

Comment: I'm implementing a shell and in this case I want to pass what is entered in the command line as a parameter to be processed somewhere else.

Comment: A good way would be to try, and then see if you have any specific problems. This is not a good or answerable question in its current form.

Comment: I'm sorry you're having difficulty understanding.  I'm not sure how exactly to make it clearer.  Let's try this, how could I use a printf statement to print out the contents pass as "line"

Comment: @GasperGulotta You could make it clearer by answering a yes/no-question such as *Is this the same as the second parameter to the main function (commonly called argv)?* with either a *yes* or a *no*.

Comment: I'm not really sure, it seems to be, but there is no argc

Comment: That seemed to work, now I just have an issue somewhere else in my main code.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Typically when you get the command line in form of a char** it is already broken down into single words, or better, single entities on the command line:

```
binary-name arg1 arg2 "arg3 arg3" arg4
```

In this example, `arg3 arg3` is a single entity (you will not get the quotes).

However, to correctly read the char** you need to know the number of words! That is why in a C program, `main()` is called with the arguments argc (number of words) and argv (char**). Then you can access argv[0] … argv[argc-1]. In our example:

- argv[0] -> `binary-name`
- argv[1] -> `arg1`
- …

Comment: Well for my purposes I will know how many words "should" be entered.  Since this is different from a main() function, am I still able to somehow work with this line?

Comment: @GasperGulotta  as long as you don't overrun the end of the argv array.  which is why you need the count, but if you got a fixed count or something, go for it.

Comment: It is very dangerous to operate on an assumption like this! Wrong user input may make your program crash or overwise misbehave. Your program should always be able to cope with wrong user input. Don't write a program like that, it is where security nightmares come from!